# how to create html string dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, html

In my C# code I am generating dynamic HTML and want to pass a parameter. So I tried this:

```
var CityName = "Barcelona";
var Id = 3;
myHtml = "<a onclick='increaseLikes(" + Id + ",'" + CityName + "')'>";
```

but it's rendering out like this:

```
<a onclick="increaseLikes(4," href="#" Barcelona')'="">
```

How would I change my code to produce valid HTML and JS?

Comment: With the code you provide, there is no reason `href="#"` appears. Maybe you could show a bit more.

And is there any reason using var over `String` or `Int` ?

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois why not using var? Its pretty much opinion based. code styling preferences ... please don't start this code war in comments again ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you  need to use Double quotes while creating html.

like..

```
     string  myHtml = "<a onclick='increaseLikes(" + Id + ",\"" + CityName + "\")'>";
```

So your output will be

```
<a onclick='increaseLikes(3,"Barcelona")'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you expect to have `<a onclick='increaseLikes(3,"Barcelona")'>`

You could change the line

```
myHtml = "<a onclick='increaseLikes(" + Id + ",'" + CityName + "')'>";
```

to

```
myHtml = string.Format(@"<a onclick='increaseLikes({0}, ""{1}"")'>", Id, CityName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should close your anchor tag properly.

```
string myHtml = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"increaseLikes(" + Id + ",\'" + CityName + "');\">...</a>";
```

Comment: I think (hope?) anchor won't be composed of only the line in the OP. If it is, how would you be able to click on this link that has no content? There should be a text / image followed by a `</a>` after this line. So closing the tag may not be mentioned here